# comboBox -- saving valueMember but showing displayMember

Tags: combobox

Just starting to use VS2013. Have several projects that I am porting from older technology. This should be really simple, so I am sure I am missing something easy.

The combo box is used to build a record. There is an ID field and a Description field. Very simple. I am trying to show the Description (which is text), but save the ID (which is int).

```
DataSource = table1BindingSource
DisplayMember = Description
ValueMember = ID

Databinding.Text = table2BindingSource.field1
```

I have tried setting

```
Databinding.SelectedValue = ID
```

and

```
Databinding.SelectedItem = ID
```

It displays in the dropdown correctly. It displays in the field correctly, using the Description. But value must not be associated with the field correctly, because I cannot save or move to the next record. Looks like the Description is getting put in the field1, and as it is int, it is not accepting it.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I got it. For text boxes, I had been assigning

```
DataBinding.Text = Table1.field
```

So, I was trying to assign for combo boxes

```
DataSource = Table1
DisplayMember = Table1.description
ValueMember - Table1.code
```

**and**

```
DataBinding.SelectedValue = Table1.code
DataBinding.Text = Table2.field
```

I finally removed the Text statement and assigned

```
DataBinding.SelectedValue = Table2.field
```

And it all worked as desired.